# Wireguard connection problem

Tags: networking, opensuse, wireguard

We are starting using WireGuard in company, and seems like I am the only one who has problem with using it.

When I tracepath to connect on one of our servers, it won't even let me connect from my localhost. I was using OpenVPN with no problems, but WireGueard seems to have some, which I really cant figure out.

I tryed to disable IPv6 on my side if it will help, but did not, and cant find any other solution.

```
tracepath servername.tld                                                                                                                                                                            ─╯
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1420
 1:  no reply
```

Comment: You'll have to provide your configuration, as well as peer configuration, especially about routes and AllowedIPs. Note that the `wg-quick` command does more than just creating a WireGuard interface: it can also mingle with policy routing. In case of doubt, try again using only the basic `ip {link|address|route}` commands along the `wg`command to check each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was bug in WG which was not routing packets propertly.

My collegue from L3 department wrote hot fix, this issue was reported as bug.

```
PostUp = MYDEFROUTE=`ip ro sh | grep default | awk '{print $3}'| head -n1`; for peer in ip.addresses.here; do ip ro add $peer/32 via $MYDEFROUTE; done
PostDown = for peer in ip.addresses; do ip ro del $peer/32; done
```

Comment: More likely a bug in the wg-quick's configuration (which OP didn't provide).